# The code will count the number of times a name appears in a column and will analyze the date when the data was stored in different Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I updated the code with the suggestions and worl, thank you all

But, I have another problem. I need to do this for every month of the year and for all the names on the worksheet (about 20 names).

This way the code will be very long, do you have any suggestions to make it more automated?

'''

```
Sub CountHSEcards()

Sub CountHSEcards()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Br As Worksheet
Set Sh = Sheets("Planilha1")
Set Br = Sheets("Brasil")

NultimaCelula = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To NultimaCelula

    If InStr(Sh.Range(CStr("AD" & i + 1)).Value, "Lucas") > 0 Then

        If Month(Sh.Range("AC" & i + 1).Value) = 1 Then
            Br.Range("C4") = Br.Range("C4").Value + 1
        End If

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

'''
[image: Sheet: Planilha1]

[image: Sheet: Brasil]

Comment: What is the value of `NultimaCelula`? (and where is that variable declared? are you not using `Option Explicit`?) Why is `NultimaCelula` (a row number) being compared to a `Month` number? Is `NultimaCelula` guaranteed to be between 1 and 12?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I did what you told me. However, I still haven't been successful.

I will answer the questions in the comments by topic

1 - Yes, all these worksheets are in the active workbook.
2 - I separated the statements, I didn't know that thanks for the advice.
3.1 - NultimaCelula is the count of rows filled in the Worksheet (Worksheet1), represented by Sh. I took the test is working well
3.2 - I had forgotten to declare the variable, it is an integer.
3.3 - The variable NultimaCelula should be used to scan all the filled lines, it is not used to compare.

Comment: "variable NultimaCelula should be used to scan all the filled lines, it is not used to compare" - except, it is. The `i` loop runs from `1` to `NultimaCelula`, and then proceeds to compare `i` against the result of the `Month` function. Therefore, there's an implicit assumption that `NultimaCelula` is between 1 and 12 too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the code worked.

But, I have another problem. I need to do this for every month of the year and for all the names on the worksheet (about 20 names).

This way the code will be very long, do you have any suggestions to make it more automated?

Answer (score 0):

I could not test if the program is doing porecisely what you need because I do not know precisely your data in the columns and what you expect, but this code could work properly in my opinion (every variables seem to be correctly read) :

```
Sub CountHSEcards()

Dim Sh, Br As Worksheet
Set Sh = Sheets("Planilha1")
Set Br = Sheets("Brazil")

NultimaCelula = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To NultimaCelula

    Sh.Select
    If InStr(Range(CStr("AD" & i + 1)).Value, "") > 0 Then

        If Month(Sh.Range(CStr("C" & i + 1)).Value) = i Then
            Br.Range(CStr("C" & i + 3)) = Br.Range(CStr("C" & i + 3)).Value + 1
        End If

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

You chose a notation for the range of a string type. So "AD" for example is OK. However, after you had directly an integer (i or i + x) to this string. It is problematic because it is a mix between different type. You can do like that, but after you convert the overall operation as a string (with CStr). Thus, the range has a string as argument and the address is ok.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not seeing where the OP is using the `+` operator for string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's still not working. I really don't know why

Comment: Hi @Livo123. When you say it is not working, it means you have an error message or the program does not express the functionality you expect ? If it is the second option, I think the code you really need is more complex. In regard of the sheets, I understand that you want monitor the number of ID Incident attributed to the colleagues, regarding the region (or country) and the date (month). Moreover you plan to design your excel file as : a data sheet (like a log file) and a sheet for each region. In these region's sheets, you have colleagues (A), months (B) and counts (C). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, with the help of the comments, the code worked well

```
Sub CountHSEcards()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Br As Worksheet
Set Sh = Sheets("Banco De Dados")
Set Br = Sheets("Brasil")
Dim z As Integer
Dim h As Integer

NultimaCelula = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Br.Range("C4" & ":C1000") = Empty
z = 17
h = 16
For i = 1 To NultimaCelula

    For x = 1 To 12

        If InStr(Sh.Range(CStr("AD" & i + 1)).Value, "Andrea Ramos") > 0 Then

            If Month(Sh.Range("C" & i + 1).Value) = x Then
                Br.Range("C" & x + 3) = Br.Range("C" & x + 3).Value + 1
                Br.Range("C16").FormulaLocal = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C4:C15"))
            End If

        End If

    Next x
Next i 

End Sub
```